# High speed communication between GCP instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, distributed-computing, hpc

I'm trying to get some advice on the best way to set up compute cluster on GCP for ML training. The job I'm currently working on has exceeded the ability of the maximum 8 V100 GPU's I can attach to a GCP instance, so I would like to run two instances and run a distributed job across all 16 GPUs. My codebase is already capable of doing this, I just need to work out the details of properly configuring the VPC network. I have done a lot of searching, but I can't seem to find any information from google related to high speed communication between instances. In order for this cluster to run effectively, I need to be able to sync gradients between nodes very quickly. For most on-premise ML HPC servers, 100 gigabit ethernet or Infiniband is used. Does GCP offer anything that would achieve this type of low latency high throughput comm between instances? Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit:

For clarification, when running iperf3, I get around 200~ MB/sec between instances on the internal IPs. This speed will bottleneck insanely. With modern Infiniband connected servers (typically used for HPC and deep learning clusters) you would be looking at upwards of 20GB/second. 200MB/sec will cause the performance to negatively scale(by a massive amount) across nodes. The current bottleneck is simply the p2p speed between GPUs on the same machine (in the case of V100s, they are using an NVSwitch setup similar to the dgx-2 with SXM2 so it blazing fast). Any networking between nodes needs to compete with that speed. I take it GCP doesn't offer any faster networking for HPC type workloads?

Comment: My understanding is that compute engines within the same zone are already maximally optimized for communications using their internal (RFC 1918) IP addresses.  There is nothing further that needs to be done to improve on either latency or bandwidth.   I'd suggest firing up two compute instances and running some network tests between them ... for example using iperf3.

Comment: You are doing something fundamentally wrong i.e. when you say " I would like to run two instances and run a distributed job across all 16 GPU"   --> You should run this job as a different job i.e. on Cloud ML engine https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/ or see this link for reference https://medium.com/searce/creating-deep-learning-models-training-and-deploying-it-on-google-cloud-ml-engine-using-9a4ed6a84076

Comment: I'm already running the training as a distributed job on a single instance. That is, each GPU get its own dedicated Python processes(each GPU acts as a node), and the backward pass through the net acts as a synchronization point between nodes. Communication between processes happens over TCP. This is the most performant way to parallelize a model and it what you will hear being referred to as "distributed training" when referencing deep learning systems. Since the model is already using the localhost to perform reductions between nodes, it is trivial to scale this to multiple machines.

Comment: How did you created an cluster ? On your own OR  you use standard cluster of dataproc. Please be precise in writing question https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/create-cluster

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: My apologies. It was not my intention to spam tags. I figured that the deep learning community would be the main consumers of the server architecture in question, so I thought it was relevant.

Comment: @Inder R Singh I'm not using any specialty means of creating a cluster per se. Just creating multiple compute engine instances in the same region/zone and VPC and communicating over their internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing anything other than super fast networking, I would ensure that both machines are in the same VPC in the same region and zone.  Make sure firewall rules between the machines allows for traffic to flow.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [Premium Tier](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/) network, your traffic will use Google High Performance Network. In that case, you just need to make sure that your machines sit on the same zone which will address your speed requirements above.